# Angular upgrade from version 4 to 14 with primeNG giving error for primeNG components

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

We are upgrading angular from version 4 to 14. We have successfully upgraded upto angular version 13 but when we upgrade angular version 13 to 14 getting error at runtime with primeNG components. currently we are using PrimeNG version 4.1.0.

Error from primgNG components -

```
core.mjs:9171 ERROR Error: NG0202
    at ɵɵinvalidFactoryDep (core.mjs:4798:11)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.Dropdown_Factory [as factory] (ɵfac.js? [sm]:1:1)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:3523:44)
    at instantiateAllDirectives (core.mjs:12731:27)
    at createDirectivesInstances (core.mjs:12155:5)
    at ɵɵelementStart (core.mjs:15285:9)
    at EncryptDecryptComponent_Template (template.html:102:15)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:12126:9)
    at renderView (core.mjs:11948:13)
    at renderComponent (core.mjs:13134:5)
```

Kindly suggest way forward to upgrade angular to latest stable version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrimeNG version must [match](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v12-0-0-is-here/) the Angular version in the major part. So, if you're trying to upgrade to Angular v14, then you should also bump the PrimeNG version to v14.

You may also find the PrimeNG [migration guide](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/wiki/Migration-Guide) useful.